# In which state will this mutex coordinated threads end up?

Tags: mutex, semaphore

I have a theoretical question about what will happen to this setup. If I have the following setup, is this a deadlock or what exactly will happen?

We have the three processes I, A and B in that order in a fifo queue. Process I initializes these Mutex and variables and terminates:

```
global int i = 1;
global mutex a = false;
global mutex b = true;
```

then Process A gets activated (next in queue) with following code:

```
while(i < 4) {
    down(a)
    i = i / 2 + 2
    up(b)
}
```

So the loop will begin and process A will get locked out as mutex `a` is not free. Thus it will be removed from running queue and sleep (and inserted in a's queue). Now Process B comes alive with the following code:

```
while(i < 4) {
    down(b)
    i = i + 1
    up(a)
}
```

So at this moment `b` is not locked so B enters and `i` is now 2. **Then B unlocks `a` which enqeues Process A in our process queue, but `a` is still locked as the `a`'s queue was not empty before unlocking?** If thats the case B will next hit `down(b)` again and lock itself out of excecution? `b` will remember B in its own queue and put B to sleep. But now A can execute again ofcourse but will hit `down(a)` while `a` is still locked? Thus both Processes are out of Process queue never to run again?

This is kinda what I understand from our informatics lecture but is it true? The processes would have to wait for an extern process to ultimatively unlock a right?

Answer (score 1):

> Then B unlocks a which enqeues Process A in our process queue, **but a is still locked**

You said it correctly first - `B` unlocks `a`, so `a` is in unlocked state. `A` can lock it and continue execution.

The resulting sequence is:

- `A` tries to lock `a` and sleeps.
- `B` locks `b` and increases `i` from 1 to 2.
- `B` unlocks `a`, waking `A`.
- `B` locks `b` and sleeps.
- `A` does `i = i / 2 + 1` (`i` becomes 3) and unlocks `b`, waking `B`.
- `A` locks `a` and sleeps.
- `B` increments `i` from 3 to 4.
- `B` unlocks `a`, waking `A` and exits.
- `A` does `i = i / 2 + 1` (`i` remains 4) and unlocks `b` (does not affect `B` as it has exited) and exits.

---

What you call mutexes is usually called "semaphores" or "binary semaphores". The term "mutex" is usually used for a restricted version of a binary semaphore: always created in an unlocked state, can only be unlocked by the same thread that locks it.

Comment: Oh I see, A reawakes already behind the down(a) instruction right? In my mind A whyever kinda started doing the whole instructions again which was the fault in my thinking. Thank you very much for clarification.

Comment: `A` first sleeps in `down(a)` and gets awaken once `a` gets unlocked by `B` in `up(a)`.